# Better string escaping for hg

Tags: text-processing, mercurial

So periodically I remove files that are listed as missing by the version control system hg. What I've noticed is that this (admittedly ugly) script I have does not properly escape strings:

```
hg status | grep ! | colrm 1 2 | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs hg remove
```

It works in a lot of cases, but some strange strings like `recognition-systems2013/20110531-information-fusion.key/\!\(\*-4.pdf` cause it to break. Incidentally hg tells me these strings are not "Windows safe"...whatever the hell that means.

Can someone work out a better way to remove the files hg lists as "!" or missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use:

```
hg addremove
```

for that *after I removed any cruft from the checked out directory* (or after I added patterns to the `.hgignore` file).

`hg addremove -h` tells you:

```
Add all new files and remove all missing files from the repository.
```

Mercurial complains about the `*` in the file name. Which is a reserved character that can not be used in file names on Windows. However that message itself goes to `stderr` and should not affect the functioning of the pipes.

An altnernative is to use:

```
hg remove --after
```

which marks files that are removed but comments on all the files (those that are still there as well as those removed) and does not seem to react to the `--quiet` option.

Comment: A good solution for most folks, but I'd like to add and remove in separate steps.

Comment: @speciousfool That is what I suspected might be the case, and why I highlighted that you have to remove the added files. I updated the answer with an alternative which for me is unusable because of the verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

When `xargs` sees `\!\(\*-4.pdf` in its input, it understands `!(*-4.pdf`. If you use `xargs`, you need to produce input that matches its input syntax, which is unlike anything else out there. Merely adding a backslash before spaces only copes with spaces.

On Linux, *BSD and OSX, `xargs` supports the option `-0`, which tells it to act on records separated by null bytes with no quoting. `hg status -0` produces records that are separated by null bytes. What remains is to process adapt the intermediate processing to cope with nulls instead of newlines as separators.

With GNU awk or any other awk that supports null bytes as record separators (I think the BSD/OSX awk does), you can switch your transformation to awk.

```
hg status -0 |
awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '/^!/ {print substr($0, 3)}' |
xargs -0 hg remove
```